# ASPX: Print server-side PDF at client-printer

Tags: asp.net, pdf, printing, interop

I create pdf-files and store them at the webserver.
I create the files with Word.Interop. Printing the files out with Document.PrintOut would start a printjob at the server-printer

The user can download his pdf-files and he should also be able to print them on his own printer.

How is this possible?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't interact with a client's printer directly from a server. This is due to browser security restrictions.

You can however invoke the print dialog box using javascript.

```
var pdf = window.open(PATH_TO_PDF);
pdf.print();
```

Try to keep this on a javascript button.

A lot of browsers block scripts that try to open javascript windows directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can affect client's printer from server code, maybe you can generate some javascript at server side which can at least open print dialog in browser.